# Replacing app launcher icon in flutter with new icon

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was looking for changing the `app icon` of my current app. I cane around the package name `flutter_launcher_icons`.

I also found I can do by putting an image in `mipmap-xxxhdpi` in `android/app/res` folder. And it works.

So my question is why we need additional package(`flutter_launcher_icons`) for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you use the package [`flutter_launcher_icons`](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons) it will automatically generate different icon sizes for the app which is better than just putting an image in `mipmap-xxxhdpi` in `android/app/res`.

Example, if you add `flutter_launcher_icons` to the `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dev_dependencies: 
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon" 
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

Then execute the following:

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

It will generate all the icons under different sizes in the `res` folder for android and `Assets.xcassets` for ios.

Check here for more information:

https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons